# Propensity score matching using "Matching" Package, including visualization and result table

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I need to do the propensity score matching using the package `Matching` in R. Unlike the `MatchIt` package, `Matching` does not include any visualization step and a comprehensive result table.

The result of `MatchBalance()` will create a long table for each variables include std, mean, diff, max, raw, eQQ diff, T-test p-value, and other results. But what I want is a integrated table with all variables and results.

Here is the results from `MatchBalance()`:

```
mb <- MatchBalance(treat ~ age + educ+black + hisp + married + nodegr + u74 + u75 + 
                     re75 + re74 + I(re74*re75), match.out=mout, nboots=500)
```

### The results from "Matching"

[image: The results from "Matching"]

### But what I want is like below (from the `MatchIt` package):

[image: results with integrated table.]

And visualization like plots of diff mean between before matching and after matching.

Answer (score 0):

The image you linked for the `MatchIt` output is actually from `cobalt`, a package I wrote, not `MatchIt`. `cobalt` is fully compatible with output from `Matching`, so you can use the same commands and get the same output. Using `cobalt`, you would run

```
bal.tab(m.out, treat ~ age + educ + black + hisp + married + nodegr + u74 + u75 + re75 + re74 + I(re74*re75), 
        data = lalonde, v.threshold = 2, ks.threshold = .05)
```

You can create visualizations using `love.plot` and `bal.plot` as well. There is a [section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt_A1_other_packages.html#using-bal.tab-with-matching) in one of the `cobalt` vignettes that explains how to use it with `Matching`.